# Does android apps without hamburger menu exists?

Tags: android, user-interface, sidebar, hamburger-menu

We trying to decide on the main navigation structure for our app.
I have read all there is about the disadvantages of the hamburger menu (aka side-menu, drawer).

The use of a visible navigation bar (instead of the hamburger menu) makes sense and it can feet our design since we don't many screens to navigate.

For iOS users we found some examples of the navigation bar, like this one in Whatsapp:
[image]

It's quite a common pattern in iOS and it seems like iOS users are familiar with it.

But the same can't be said aboud android. **I could not find a single app** that uses this kind of main icons navigation bar.

Can someone provide an example of a "top" app that uses it?

Will it be wrong to build it like so, isn't it a deprecated pattern when developing for android ?

Comment: Its called a tabhost in android and its commonly used, not deprecated whatsoever

Answer (score 2):

The rule number one: Do not copy UI patterns from other platforms.

The pattern you are looking for is called [Tabs](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#). These tabs are, unlike iOS, positioned on the top of the screen.

You can find it for example in the Google Play app.